# Inflation Protected Bonds, How to find an index of them?

Tags: investing, inflation, securities

I came across TIPS in Graham’s security analysis book. I attempted to find them on DEGIRO but and found indices of such:

iShares $ TIPS UCITS ETF EUR Hedged (Acc)

Q1: How do you decipher that?

Q2. Is there an index site for EU issued inflation protected securities?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is an ETF, not an Index:

- TIPS = US Treasury Inflation Protected Securities
- UCITS = Undertakings for Collective Investment in Transferable Securities (EU regulated)
- ETF = Exchange Traded Fund
- EUR = Demoninated in Euros
- Hedged = currency risk (USD/EUR) is hedged
- Acc = Accumulating (does not pay dividends, but reinvests them)

Q2 is off-topic (request for resource), but note that this fund tracks the Bloomberg US Government Inflation-Linked Bond Index.

You can also search for inflation-based ETFs on iShare's site to find *funds* that meet your criteria and look at what indexes they track.